# Updating the UI during a after a button push

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have been thinking about adding a button to a View which when pressed adds another view on the bottom. It would resemble the Clock application that comes preinstalled in which you push a view in form of an alarm which is then added to a list.
Does anyone have any experience with how to implement that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the documentation for [ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html), particularly the `setAdapter()` method.  You'll want to have some sort of backing collection most likely as the adapter, such as an `ArrayAdapter`, to which you can add new items, and have them populate into the list.

Answer (score 0):

Use a listview, populate it.

Then when you press the button, add something to your data, then:

> public void notifyDataSetChanged ()
>
> Since: API Level 1 Notifies the attached observers that the underlying
>   data has been changed and any View reflecting the data set should
>   refresh itself.